# How to make Ubuntu remember last used folder/location?

Tags: 22.04, directory

How can I configure Ubuntu to remember last used folder/location?

Suppose I have uploaded some files to google drive from a specific folder in Ubuntu. I want Ubuntu to remember last used folder/location when I next time perform the same task. Is there a way to achieve this?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that with `dconf-editor`.

First, install and launch it `sudo apt install dconf-editor` then `dconf-editor` then in `dconf-editor` go to `/org/gtk/settings/file-chooser/` you will see a `last-folder-uri` it store the last used folder, for example to have `Downloads` as your default folder, juste write `file:///home/your-username/Downloads` ( dont forget to replace `username` ) then if you want it to remember the last used folder just enable the `remember-last-folder` option.

Comment: Where do I have to write my folder or location path i.e, ```file:///home/your-username/Downloads```? In ```custom value``` section? And I can see no ```remember-last-folder``` option present there.